# Symbolic link recursion - what makes it "reset"?

Tags: bash, symlink

I wrote a little bash script to see what happens when I keep following a symbolic link that points to the same directory. I was expecting it to either make a very long working directory, or to crash. But the result surprised me...

```
mkdir a
cd a

ln -s ./. a

for i in `seq 1 1000`
do
  cd a
  pwd
done
```

Some of the output is

```
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a
${HOME}/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
${HOME}/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
```

what is happening here?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Patrice identified the source of the problem in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79576/22565), but if you want to know how to get from there to why you get that, here's the long story.

The current working directory of a process is nothing you'd think too complicated. It is an attribute of the process which is a handle to a file of type directory where relative paths (in system calls made by the process) start from. When resolving a relative path, the kernel doesn't need to know the (a) full path to that current directory, it just reads the directory entries in that directory file to find the first component of the relative path (and `..` is like any other file in that regard) and continues from there.

Now, as a user, you sometimes like to know where that directory lies in the directory tree. With most Unices, the directory tree is a tree, with no loop. That is, there's only one path from the root of the tree (`/`) to any given file. That path is generally called the canonical path.

To get the path of the current working directory, what a process has to do is just walk up (well *down* if you like to see a tree with its root at the bottom) the tree back to the root, finding the names of the nodes on the way.

For instance, a process trying to find out that its current directory is `/a/b/c`, would open the `..` directory (relative path, so `..` is the entry in the current directory) and look for a file of type directory with the same inode number as `.`, find out that `c` matches, then opens `../..` and so on until it finds `/`. There's no ambiguity there.

That's what the `getwd()` or `getcwd()` C functions do or at least used to do.

On some systems like modern Linux, there's a system call to return the canonical path to the current directory which does that lookup in kernel space (and allows you to find your current directory even if you don't have read access to all its components), and that's what `getcwd()` calls there. On modern Linux, you can also find the path to the current directory via a readlink() on `/proc/self/cwd`.

That's what most languages and early shells do when returning the path to the current directory.

In your case, you can call `cd a` as may times as you want, because it's a symlink to `.`, the current directory doesn't change so all of `getcwd()`, `pwd -P`, `python -c 'import os; print os.getcwd()'`, `perl -MPOSIX -le 'print getcwd'` would return your `${HOME}`.

Now, symlinks went complicating all that.

`symlinks` allow jumps in the directory tree. In `/a/b/c`, if `/a` or `/a/b` or `/a/b/c` is a symlink, then the canonical path of `/a/b/c` would be something completely different. In particular, the `..` entry in `/a/b/c` is not necessarily `/a/b`.

In the Bourne shell, if you do:

```
cd /a/b/c
cd ..
```

Or even:

```
cd /a/b/c/..
```

There's no guarantee you'll end up in `/a/b`.

Just like:

```
vi /a/b/c/../d
```

is not necessarily the same as:

```
vi /a/b/d
```

`ksh` introduced a concept of a *logical current working directory* to somehow work around that. People got used to it and POSIX ended up specifying that behaviour which means most shells nowadays do it as well:

For the `cd` and `pwd` builtin commands (**and only for them** (though also for `popd`/`pushd` on shells that have them)), the shell maintains its own idea of the current working directory. It's stored in the `$PWD` special variable.

When you do:

```
cd c/d
```

even if `c` or `c/d` are symlinks, while `$PWD` containes `/a/b`, it appends `c/d` to the end so `$PWD` becomes `/a/b/c/d`. And when you do:

```
cd ../e
```

Instead of doing `chdir("../e")`, it does `chdir("/a/b/c/e")`.

And the `pwd` command only returns the content of the `$PWD` variable.

That's useful in interactive shells because `pwd` outputs a path to the current directory that gives information on how you got there and as long as you only use `..` in arguments to `cd` and not other commands, it's less likely to surprise you, because `cd a; cd ..` or `cd a/..` would generally get you back to where you were.

Now, `$PWD` is not modified unless you do a `cd`. Until the next time you call `cd` or `pwd`, a lot of things could happen, any of the components of `$PWD` could be renamed. The current directory never changes (it's always the same inode, though it could be deleted), but its path in the directory tree could change completely. `getcwd()` computes the current directory each time it's called by walking down the directory tree so its information is always accurate, but for the logical directory implemented by POSIX shells, the information in `$PWD` might become stale. So upon running `cd` or `pwd`, some shells may want to guard against that.

In that particular instance, you see different behaviours with different shells.

Some like `ksh93` ignore the problem completely, so will return incorrect information even after you call `cd` (and you wouldn't see the behaviour that you're seeing with `bash` there).

Some like `bash` or `zsh` do check that `$PWD` is still a path to the current directory upon `cd`, but not upon `pwd`.

pdksh does check upon both `pwd` and `cd` (but upon `pwd`, does not update `$PWD`)

`ash` (at least the one found on Debian) does not check, and when you do `cd a`, it actually does `cd "$PWD/a"`, so if the current directory has changed and `$PWD` no longer points to the current directory, it will actually not change to the `a` directory in the current directory, but the one in `$PWD` (and return an error if it doesn't exist).

If you want to play with it, you can do:

```
cd
mkdir -p a/b
cd a
pwd
mv ~/a ~/b 
pwd
echo "$PWD"
cd b
pwd; echo "$PWD"; pwd -P # (and notice the bug in ksh93)
```

in various shells.

In your case, since you're using `bash`, after a `cd a`, `bash` checks that `$PWD` still points to the current directory. To do that, it calls `stat()` on the value of `$PWD` to check its inode number and compare it with that of `.`.

But when the looking up of the `$PWD` path involves resolving too many symlinks, that `stat()` returns with an error, so the shell cannot check whether `$PWD` still corresponds to the current directory, so it computes it a again with `getcwd()` and updates `$PWD` accordingly.

Now, to clarify Patrice's answer, that check of number of symlinks encountered while looking up a path is to guard against symlink loops. The simplest loop can be made with

```
rm -f a b
ln -s a b
ln -s b a
```

Without that safe guard, upon a `cd a/x`, the system would have to find where `a` links to, finds it's `b` and is a symlink which links to `a`, and that would go on indefinitely. The simplest way to guard against that is to give up after resolving more than an arbitrary number of symlinks.

Now back to the *logical current working directory* and why it's not so good a feature. It's important to realise that it's only for `cd` in the shell and not other commands.

For instance:

```
cd -- "$dir" &&  vi -- "$file"
```

is not always the same as:

```
vi -- "$dir/$file"
```

That's why you'll sometimes find that people recommend to always use `cd -P` in scripts to avoid confusion (you don't want your software to handle an argument of `../x` differently from other commands just because it's written in shell instead of another language).

The `-P` option is to disable the *logical directory* handling so `cd -P -- "$var"` actually does call `chdir()` on the content of `$var` (at least as long as `$CDPATH` it not set, and except when `$var` is `-` (or possibly `-2`, `+3`... in some shells) but that's another story). And after a `cd -P`, `$PWD` will contain a canonical path.

Comment: Sweet Jesus! Thanks for such a comprehensive answer, it's really quite interesting :)

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot! I feel like I *kinda* knew all of these things, but I'd never understood or thought about how they all came together. Great explanation.

Comment: Nice answer. May I ask what abnormality should be observed in the 9 lines script above? In the 5th line, `mv ~/a ~/b` renames `~/a` to `~/b`. It has nothing to do with the subdirectory `~/a/b`. In my BASH, both `pwd` and `echo $PWD` prints `/home/midnite/a`, the path before the rename. After `cd b`, both `pwd` and `echo $PWD` are updated to the correct path. In this example, I am not able to spot the different between `pwd` and `$PWD`. In my opinion, `pwd` is more reliable than `$PWD`, as `$PWD` can be set to arbitrary values, but `pwd` equals to the actual current working directory, isn't it?

Comment: @midnite It might be easier to see if you put something like `printf "N ";` in front of each `pwd` or `echo` command in the script so you can track which command is printing which output line.  In my case, the output doesn't change after the `mv` command when it shows a path which no longer exists.  Only after the `cd` command, does the shell realize that its idea of the logical wd is no longer valid and it recalculates.  I notice that my bash 5.1.16(1) will also change (fix) the output of `pwd` after a call to `pwd -P`.

Answer (score 45):

This is the result of a hard-coded limit in the Linux kernel source; to prevent denial-of-service, the limit on the number of nested symlinks is 40 (found in the [`follow_link()` function](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.12/fs/namei.c#L1140) inside `fs/namei.c`, called by `nested_symlink()` in the kernel source).

You would probably get a similar behaviour (and possibly another limit than 40) with other kernels supporting symlinks.

Comment: Is there a reason for it to "reset", rather than just stop. i.e. `x%40` rather than `max(x,40)`. I guess you can still see you've changed directory.

Comment: A link to the source, for anyone else curious: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.6/fs/namei.c#L818