# Can a bash script tell what directory the user is when they run the script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is it possible for a shell script to know the directory the user is in when they run it? I am trying to develop a script like this which runs through a list of subdirectories and runs some git commands on them. One way might be to pass `pwd` to it, but there are some additional parameters it will require which is why I want to use a built-in function to get the working directory.

The example assumes the current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */ ; do
  echo ""
  echo "===================="
  echo ""
  echo "$d"

  git -C "$d" remote show origin
  echo ""
  echo "===================="
  echo ""
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with using pwd in the bash-script?

Comment: I don't do a lot of shell scripting and even with scripts I write I have to read them again to understand the constructs I use, so the less lines I write the better it is for me.

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79571/symbolic-link-recursion-what-makes-it-reset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX shells (like `bash`) and `fish` make the path of the current working directory (a process property inherited by children and preserved across execution of commands) in the `$PWD` special variable in POSIX shells. The equivalent for `csh`-like shells is `$cwd`.

The variable is dynamic. Its content may change after you call a command that changes the current directory like `cd` (or `pushd`/`popd` in some shells). POSIX shells also maintain a `$OLDPWD` variable that contains the previous working directory from before you called a successful `cd`/`pushd`/`popd`.

The `pwd` command prints one path to the current directory. In POSIX shells, that command is often built-in and just prints the content of `$PWD`.

If you want to know what the working directory at the time the script started, you'll need to record it at the start  of your script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
original_PWD=$PWD
...
cd ...
```

To know the current working directory of your parent process, on GNU/Linux, you can do

```
parent_PWD=$(readlink -ve "/proc/$PPID/cwd")
```

though you may not always have permission to get that information. If your parent died, you'll be adopted by `init` or by the child sub-reaper if any. However `$PPID` will *not* be updated, so you may get the cwd of the wrong process in that case (if the the pid of your parent has been reused).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the script inherits the current directory of the shell/program that runs it. So all file name references would be relative to that, unless the script does a `cd` itself. Knowing the location of the script file itself is harder to do, and may be nigh impossible.

Comment: Is there a built in variable that refers to the directory the user started in, in case the script itself executes additonal `cd` commands?
PS. The location of the script itself is a solved problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself

Comment: _Knowing the location of the script file itself is harder to do, and may be nigh impossible:_ `SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd \"$(dirname \"$0\")\" && pwd)"`

Comment: @aff, try that when the script is started with say `(exec -a hello /path/to/script.sh)`. The thing is that `$0` can contain _anything_ the process calling `execve()` wants it to contain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an environment variable for this, but you can make your own variable to use pretty easily without many commands.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
starting_dir=$(pwd)  #use pwd to get the starting directory

#do things
cd some_example_dir/
#do more things

cd $starting_dir  #go back to the directory
```

In this case, you're just saving the starting directory's path as a string in the variable `$starting_dir`. It's saved as an absolute path, so you can `cd` to it any time.